# Pandas empty string to integer

Tags: pandas

Have a csv file which contains several columns, some columns are mixed with letters and numbers. Need remove letters and set to null  and change the column to integer but got some error. It seems Pandas recently added nullable integer type. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html. But I still get errors while changing to int. I need keep the column as int so I could not use another way  workaround to set the column to float with NAN in the column.
Data looks like this:

```
 id    count      volume   
 001,     A   ,       1
 002,     1   ,       2
```

Column count and volume contains values like :   '  1  ', ' 2  ','  A  ',.....

I used re module to remove  the letters and whitespace

```
df["count"] = df["count"].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\s[a-zA-Z]*', '',x))
```

Now the values in the column looks like : '1', '2','',.......

Tried to change to 'Int64' but got error:

```
  df["count"].astype(str).astype('Int64')
```

TypeError: object cannot be converted to an IntegerDtype

Any suggestion or workaround?

Comment: `df['count'] = pd.to_numeric(df['count'], errors='coerce')`

Comment: df['count'] = pd.to_numeric(df['count'], errors='coerce').astype('Int64') finally worked.

Answer (score 7):

```
 df['count'] = pd.to_numeric(df['count'], errors='coerce').astype('Int64')
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.